# print() 2 variables in Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python and came across this behavior which puzzles me.

Why does this code print out the variables enclosed by parenthesis and `\r\n`:

```
def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print(line_count, f.readline())

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

Prints:

```
(1, 'a1\r\n')
```

while this code:

```
def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print(f.readline())

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

prints without the parenthesis:

```
a1
```

Comment: You're using Python 2.

Comment: I'm guessing it's not really python 3.3.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally moved to a mac with Python 2.

Comment: @Nyxynyx Did my answer helped... if so, accept it please. And by the way, what kind of accident did move you to a mac? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, when you `print(line_count, f.readline())` you are actually saying print a tuple, which first element is `line_count` and the second element is `f.readline()`, `f.readline()` reads the entire line, with the end of line marker, in your file it is '\r\n'.

In the second case, `print (f.readline())`, you are printing just a string, not a tuple containing a string, (if you want a tuple containing just a string you should use `(mystring,)`.

The `(anystring)` notation allows you to use:

```
mystring = ('This is my '
            'very long string')
```

Instead of `print(line_count, f.readline())` you should use

```
print (str(line_count) + f.readline())
```

or

```
print ('%d %s'%(line_count, f.readline()))
```